# Why did my AJAX Accordion control stop working?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

I really don't even know where to begin.  I was trying to do some stuff with a reportviewer in an ASP.Net web app, and the next time I ran my project, the AJAX accordion stopped expanding on a completely different page. I tried re-installing the AJAXControlToolkit using NuGet, but that didn't help.  The page shows the accordion panes collapsed, and clicking on them does not cause them to expand.

edit: Ok, so there was a Javascript error on the page, but not one that I know what to do with.  The error is coming from scriptresource.axd.  The error occurs on every page in my site, and it is:

```
Sys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: elements [http://localhost:54342/ScriptResource.axd?d=oLn_YfKUbuAZmIp8wPx_MGof0M_lenV-JW2kiI5YDekmr8rZkMCuAuKyOZO06cyZlzhzJQ4BbUMfJShMBgWgM8TnLZXjah8CDfymeaxo44H_TH5anoZTptNOkXlY-ZNjFoS3wUNWvcmBHzSSm5K9ww2&t=252a36c5:4869]
```

the function in which this error is being thrown:

```
$addHandler = $type.addHandler = function DomEvent$addHandler(elements, eventName, handler, autoRemove) {
    /// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler">A cross-browser way to add a DOM event handler to an element.</summary>
    /// <param name="elements">The element or text node, or array of elements or text nodes, that exposes the event. You may also pass a DOM selector or array of DOM selectors.</param>
    /// <param name="eventName" type="String">The name of the event. Do not include the 'on' prefix, for example, 'click' instead of 'onclick'.</param>
    /// <param name="handler" type="Function">The event handler to add.</param>
    /// <param name="autoRemove" type="Boolean" optional="true" mayBeNull="true">Whether the handler should be removed automatically when the element is disposed of, such as when an UpdatePanel refreshes, or Sys.Application.disposeElement is called.</param>
    var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
        {name: "elements"},
        {name: "eventName", type: String},
        {name: "handler", type: Function},
        {name: "autoRemove", type: Boolean, mayBeNull: true, optional: true}
    ]);
    if (e) throw e;
```

^^ happens here on the last line.

it seems like I'm probably missing something simple like... adding an ID to a control somewhere or something, but I'm really just guessing.

edit 2: I found the culprit.  On the master page I had a User Control wherein I had a Modal Popup Extender that had some of its properties (OKButton, CancelButton, etc..) set to controls that didn't exist.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @rickschott not sure if I misunderstood the question or you misunderstood the question Mr.Schott.(maybe I misunderstood your comment or javascript)

Comment: @OkayGuy typically these problems are caused by some JS error that causes the page to break, and causes things like accordions not working.

Comment: Rick scott iz right. If ther is a javascript error it would appear at the bottom left hand corner of the browser. If there is an error double click the icon and a dialogue should appear with further details.

Comment: @Brian the guy is asking about the Visual studio itself that is what I understand.

Comment: @OkayGuy It's not a design-time error, but a runtime error based on the description.  Since AJAX control toolkit leverages a lot of client-script, that typically is what the error is...  I gather it's a runtime error from "the AJAX accordion stopped expanding on a completely different page" as you don't get the expand / collapse functionality in Visual Studio and the expand / collapse functionality is driven from JavaScript.

Comment: @Brian Thanks Brian, I didn't know anything about that as I said I misunderstoond JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions and sorry I wasn't able to respond sooner.  I know this wasn't the best formed question so I appreciate your trying to help.  And... you guys were totally right, there was a javascript error - I just didn't notice it because apparently Chrome doesn't notify you of JS errors unless you have the developer window open.  Anyways.... I will edit my original question to include the error I am now getting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the vague question... It boils down to: What would cause an AJAX control to unexpectedly stop working?

and the answer as pointed out in the comments is that it usually comes from a javascript error.